# UIButton Interchange with touch animation in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uitouch, caanimation

I have 5X5 button in a view.
     Based on some Condition, i want to interchange them.
     How can i know which of them is touched, if move is not possible then a message
     alert will be displayed.If the move is possible then current button should replace the
     Previous one.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Assign different tags to the buttons. In the action method, using the tag, you'll know which of them was clicked.

Comment: @ Ananth means that you have 25 buttons in a matrix and on touch each of them you want to retrieve the title of the buttons.Is it so? some code please for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you review your question as it is difficult to understand what you really want. But to know which button was touched up inside you can assign unique tags to buttons and then check for the sender's tag. Or another way, declare 25 UIButton IBOutlets (instance variables)  and connect them to the buttons in Interface Builder. And then you can check if the [sender isEqual:button1(button2 etc....)].

```
-(IBAction)buttonTouched:(UIButton*)sender{
   if (sender.tag=@"Button1")
      ..........
 }
```

or

```
IBOutlet UIButton button1;
..........
-(IBAction)buttonTouched:(UIButton*)sender{
  if ([sender isEqual:button1])
 .......
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the button if you can retreive the title of the button you can use the follwing code(if your button touch down event is connected to this function):-

```
-(void)btnClicked:(id)sender {       
    UIButton *rButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@" The button's title is %@." rButton.currentTitle);
}
```